# What is the fundamental group of a torus connected sum with a Klein bottle?

Tags: algebraic-topology

I got $\langle a,b,c,d \mid [a,b]cdc^{-1}d\rangle$ but I don't feel comfortable for some reason. Could you help me with the problem? Thanks!

Comment: You should provide more context for the type of solution you're looking for. The [classification of surfaces without boundary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_(topology)#Classification_of_closed_surfaces) is well-known, for example, so you could just look up the answer.

Comment: I just want a presentation of the fundamental group.